# Is dynamically loaded C# code can use objects of host app?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'd like to create some game engine like thing, and I want to use C# codes for this script engine.

I heard that C# codes can be dynamically compiled/loaded via Roslyn, and I become curious if the code can refer objects of host.

Let me explain. Host application has these methods and loads external codes :

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;   
(...)
static class MainApp
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // TODO : Load codes via Roslyn        
    }

    static void DoSomething()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

and loaded code has these behaviors :

```
(same namespace as host application)
...
MainApp.DoSomething(); // Is it possible?
...
```

Comment: In your plugin you can implement Invoke(ICallback callback) which the main app invokes, with ICallback declared in a separate/shared assembly which both your main app and plugin references. Then your plugin can invoke methods in the main app using the callback-interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. If the dynamically loaded code was compiled with a reference to the host application assembly, it can use **`public`** types and members from the application, just as if the application was a normal library.